# Discrete sum "wave packet" for $x\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-integrals

Let $A:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with compact support having a continuous derivative. In particular $A(k)=0$ outside some sufficiently wide interval $[k_0,k_1]$.

Define a (simplified) wave packet as
$$
U(x) = \int_{k_0}^{k_1} A(k)\cos(k x) dk
$$
I convinced myself that $\lim_{x\to\infty} |U(x)| = 0$ along the lines of
$$
|U(x)| = \left|
1/x A(k)\sin(kx)\Big|_{k_0}^{k_1} - 1/x \int_{k_0}^{k_1} A'(k)\sin(k x) dk
 \right|
$$
per integration by parts, where the the first term of the sum is zero, because $A(k_0) = A(k_1) = 0$. This leaves us with
$$
|U(x)| \leq |1/x| \int_{k_0}^{k_1}|A'(k)|\cdot|sin(kx)|dk\,.
$$
Since $A$ has compact support, so has $A'$ such there there is an $A_0$ with $A'(k)<A_0$. The sine is anyway bounded by 1 and we get
$$
|U(x)| <= |1/x| \int_{k_0}^{k_1} A_0 dk = |1/x|(k_1-k_0)A_0\,.
$$
This converges to zero for $x\to\infty$. The crucial part was that we conjured up that $1/x$ through integration by parts.

Now replace the integral by a sum and, for simplicity, reduce to just two terms:
$$
U(x) = B_0\cos(k_0 x) + B_1\cos(k_1 x)
$$
This is clearly not going to zero if the two get in phase every once in a while for $x\to\infty$, which is the case if for two integers $L$ and $N$ we have
\begin{align}
k_0 x &= 2L\pi \\
\text{and}\quad k_1 x &=  2K\pi \,.
\end{align}
Dividing on both sides we see that this requires
$$
\frac{k_0}{k_1} = \frac{L}{K} \in \mathbb{Q}\,.
$$

Finally my **question**: How does $U(x)$ behave for $x\to\infty$ if $k_0/k_1\notin\mathbb{Q}$. Does it converge to zero? Is it periodic? My hunch is that it is neither periodic nor does it converge which provides a gut feeling of "randomness".

In case someone wants so provide more insight: Can this randomness be described somehow? If it does not converge: compared to the integral version of $U$, is there some intuitive insight what the crucial difference is to the discrete sum (beyond discrete vs. continuous) that brought in the $1/x$?